# What is this odd looking tool?

Tags: tools

Neither myself nor a large group of people on a community chat can figure out what this tool is called or used for. It’s triangular with a thick solid 3 legged base, multiple flat wired blades (possibly blades), has a handle, and the rear legs are slightly higher than the front leg. We’ve had guesses (some of them hilarious) of everything from a cheese slicer, soap making tool, pastry cutter, blind cleaner, harvesting tool, to iron holder. It’s none of those. Someone must know!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to DIY! Where did you find this tool? That info might help narrow it down. Also, take the [tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour)

Comment: The blades look too thick to use as slicer well.  Does seem it might be adjustable for amount of blades.

Comment: I was going to say "combination cheese slicer/concrete trowel", but since you ruled out cheese slicer, I'd go with some sort of concrete trowel.

Comment: The standoff feet at the bottom rule out any sort of trowel. How do you know it *isn't* one of the things you listed? I think it might be for slicing fruit to go in pie. Like the fruit goes on the middle then you force it through the wedge

Comment: The type of metal suggests it's for masonry or mortar. Perhaps it's a tool to spread mortar on a hard-to-access edge and the bottom is a stopper/hard edge. A thought crossed my mind that its' for heating up and scoring something meltable but the (apparent) wooden handle would overrule that. Very peculiar tool though. Where did you find it?

Comment: @Matthew  the blades look like they have no cutting edge  on them, would tend to smash fruit/soft stuff than slice.  Might be a type of strainer, straining stones from sand(?).

Comment: Here is another idea. I vaguely remember as  a kid, helping my aunt in rugmaking. Basically, she would set up a long rug "skeleton"series of strong vertical strings, we would hook yarn on each one of them, one knot at a time. Finally, she would tamp down the completed row of knots with a special tool, but that one didn't have that thick edge. Only mentioning it here because perhaps this tool is used for something similar but narrower than the rug. In fact I found a video of Persian rug making that is similar to what I was describing https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vyQWEItxWYk&t=120s

Answer (score 13):

The mystery has been solved, and it was discovered to actually be a vintage aluminum iron stand. I had found many antique iron stands that were similarly shaped, but none had the blade like structure around it. I assume their purpose is to prevent the iron from falling off while allowing heat to escape.

[image]

Comment: Interesting. It's a very simple and effective radiator/heat dispersant

Comment: Google Image Search can be your friend in cases like this

Comment: @CarlWitthoft admittedly I tried, as well as ebay image search, with poor results, but yeah, Google **_Reverse_** Image search it's a good first resort.

Comment: The grille would be to prevent accidental burns or damage from inadvertent contact with the hot iron.

Comment: @isherwood: Or possibly put glowing coal inside? No idea.

Comment: Vintage+aluminium would be expensive (depending on how vintage).  Also aluminium is a good conductor of heat, which would cool the iron (it also holds a lot of heat, but that's only useful if used with a heat source - maybe it was.  The listing's identification of the metal *may* be incorrect (even though the purpose is probably correct)